# UCWA - contactPresence resource is missing property 'activity'

Tags: skype-for-business, lync-2013, ucwa

Via UCWA we are requesting the contactPresence of each of our contacts.

According to the API reference, the contactPresence resource should have an property 'activity' that contains:

> The contact's current activity encoded in UTF-16 and in the locale
>   specified during application creation. The value of this string is
>   localized in the current application's culture provided the localized
>   string exists in the contact's publication. Otherwise, the value of
>   this string is one of the well known activity strings in which case
>   the application is responsible for the localization. The well known
>   ones are "in-a-meeting", "urgent-interruptions-only", "on-the-phone",
>   "in-a-conference", "off-work", and "presenting".

See: https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-contactPresence

However, in our response:

`$ curl -i 'https://lyncwebsvcX.XXX.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/xxx/people/xxxxx/presence' --header "Authorization:Bearer cwt=AAEBHA....aFE"`

Returns:
`{"availability":"Offline","deviceType":"Unknown","lastActive":"\/Date(1480607186000)\/","_links":{"self":{"href":"/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/...../presence"}},"rel":"contactPresence"}`

None of the contacts has an activity-property in their contactPresence, regardless of their availability.

The server is a Lync 2013 server with cumulative updates installed (at least up to August 2016).

**edit**

It seems that there is no support for custom states in Lync 2013:

> The presence statuses are pre-set in Skype for Business (Lync), which
>   means you can’t create a custom status, but you can give your contacts
>   more details about where you are or what you’re doing by adding a
>   personal note

See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-presence-status-in-Lync-ef8998cc-7801-4b62-81ba-9a2c1630f9e5

The personal note mentioned above, seems to be available as the `contactNote` resource and not related to the availability or activity from the contact.

This however doesn't explain what the `activity` resembled and whether it can be used with Lync 2013. That part of the question remains.

Comment: This logic may only be available in Skype for Business Server 2015 or UCWA 2.0 which would not be available for Lync Server 2013.

Comment: I suspect the same, but I wasn't able to find any documentation that confirms this.